# Should a one-month internship be included in my resume?

Tags: resume

I'm currently in Year 0 in an undergraduate course in biochemistry, and I've been offered an one-month internship in **regulatory affairs** in a big pharmaceutical corporation.

The problem is: I desire to work with **lab/research** once I finish my course. Would this internship help my CV? Or it is not recommended to point it?

Thanks in advance, and pardon me for my basic english.

Answer (score 3):

If the selection was competitive what can it hurt to mention it on your resume/CV.

It shows that you are taking an interest in subjects related to your major. It shows that somebody thought you had the skills necessary for the internship.

As time goes by you will drop this from your resume, but then you will have other more relevant items to include.

Answer (score 0):

Post it as a one-line item. Bring attention to it in interviews if you want to but I usually put such positions like that which I'm proud of, for example working for my country's Finance Minister for 4 months, as "Co-operative Education" underneath Education.

Comment: I am not sure for this situation a one-line item is a good idea. The OPs CV is already going to be limited and until the OP has better content for their CV they should use the details of this internship rather than a one_line item.